# Changing the period in the setInterval() method while running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to change the period (timer) in setInterval() method without using clearInterval() of that method(Id)?

I want to make the method have an initial fixed speed and slow down over time and with the help of the setTimeout() method to finish in ten seconds for example?

If I could get some examples I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Well you can not alter the interval.

Answer (score 3):

I think an interval is the wrong thing to use. You would be better off using setTimeout and call the next timeout based on the new waiting time you want.

```js
function runIt(myFunc) {

  let waitFor = 3000;

  function executeIt () {
    myFunc();
    waitFor = waitFor - 250;
    if (waitFor>=0) {
       next();
    }
  }
  
  function next() {
    window.setTimeout(executeIt, waitFor);
  }
  next();
  
}

runIt(function (){ console.log(Date.now())})
```